# Font not applying to my app on Heroku (but works locally)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, heroku, less, sails.js

## Env

- Sails 0.12.3
- Bootstrap
- Heroku PaaS
- CloudFlare CDN

## Issue

Trying to use a different font with Bootstrap in my SailsJS application

In my `layout.ejs`

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jura:500|Open+Sans:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

In my `importer.less`

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jura:500|Open+Sans:400,300);
```

and

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif;
}
```

Assets are compiled properly locally, but when deployed to Heroku the fonts don't apply.

Any pointers how to troubleshoot this?

## grunt less --verbose

```
Running tasks: less

Running "less" task

Running "less:dev" (less) task
Verifying property less.dev exists in config...OK
Files: assets/styles/importer.less -> .tmp/public/styles/importer.css
Options: banner=""
Reading assets/styles/importer.less...OK
Writing .tmp/public/styles/importer.css...OK
File .tmp/public/styles/importer.css created
>> 1 stylesheet created.

Done, without errors.
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the app?  What do you see?

Comment: Do you mean `heroku logs`? For now I've tried `heroku run grunt less -a myapp` as it behaves just as it wouldn't be compiling my assets. I have tried `grunt build --verbose` and all seem alright. The logs don't show any errors. Anything else you suggest? cheers

Comment: What does the compiled CSS look like?  Are you looking at a non-SSL url on heroku?

Comment: Arghh! Figured it out. So stupid. I had it hooked to CloudFlare earlier and was still refreshing my URL instead of the heroku app URL. Hey thanks for engaging questions. That helped.

Answer (score 0):

This was Not a **Heroku** problem but rather a **CloudFlare** configuration trick when developing.

In **CloudFLare** main menu, select `Caching`, then find the section `Development Mode` and turn it on.

Then I was able to see my changes after each deploy `git push staging master`

[image]

Comment: I had a similar issue a couple of weeks ago and was about to reply but I see you have found the answer. I tend to clear down my cloudflare cache if I make any changes to my assets folder.

Comment: feel free to upvote question and answer. I think this is a silly mistake, but as the day goes by, we can't think of everything right? :) I am just aging ;)